# Selecting columns where only one item is true

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am using the following code to determine if any of the columns in my data table have 1065. If any of the columns do have 1065, I get "TRUE" which works perfectly. Now I want to only output true if any of the columns notcancer0:notcancer33 contains 1065 AND all the rest are NA. Other columns may contain other values like 1064, 1066, etc. But I want to output "TRUE" for the rows where there is only 1065 and all the rest of the columns contain NAs for that row. What is the best way to do this?

```
biobank_nsaid[, ischemia1 := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "1065")), .SDcols=notcancer0:notcancer33]
```

Sample data:

```
biobank_nsaid = structure(list(aspirin = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label =
 c("FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), aspirinonly = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), med0 = c(1140922174L, 1140871050L, 1140879616L, 1140909674L ), med1 = 
c(1140868226L, 1140876592L, 1140869180L, NA), med2 = c(1140879464L, NA, 
1140865016L, NA), med3 = c(1140879428L, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It sounds like you want an XOR operator, which R has as `xor()`. Change `\`|\`` in your code to `xor`. You may also want to change `\`==\`` to `%in%`... otherwise I think you'll need to also apply `is.na` somewhere. And if your column is numeric, I'd advise removing the quotes around 1065.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for the response. I ran the code and I get the same result as when I just use the | operator. For example: ```biobank_nsaid[, aspirin := Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `==`, "1140868226")), .SDcols=med0:med47]
```  versus ```biobank_nsaid[, aspirinonly := Reduce(`xor`, lapply(.SD, `%in%`, "1140868226")), .SDcols=med0:med47]``` gets me                                                                          
        aspirin aspirinonly       med0       med1       med2       med3
 1:    TRUE        TRUE 1140922174 1140868226 1140879464 1140879428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 options:

```
setDT(biobank_nsaid)[, ischemia1 := 
    rowSums(is.na(.SD))==ncol(.SD)-1L & rowSums(.SD==1140909674, na.rm=TRUE)==1L, 
    .SDcols=med0:med3]
```

Or after some boolean manipulations:

```
biobank_nsaid[, ic2 := 
    !(rowSums(is.na(.SD))!=ncol(.SD)-1L | rowSums(.SD==1140909674, na.rm=TRUE)!=1L), 
    .SDcols=med0:med3]
```